# How to animate RecyclerView height before items are shown

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

How can I, or should I say when can I animate recyclerView height before items are shown ? I can get the final height in onMeasure but the items always appear too fast and the animation doesn't work.

Any idea on how I could get this animation to work ?

Comment: You probably want to look at View.getViewTreeObserver, and the OnPreDrawListener, or OnGlobalLayoutListener objects.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I can "pause" the drawing so I can animate the RecyclerView bounds before ? Here is what I have in mind : get the final height with all items, then, before drawing the items, start the animation, and at the end of the animation finally draw the items.

Comment: Depending on what you return (true or false) from your onPreDrawListener, it'll skip drawing that frame.  "Return true to proceed with the current drawing pass, or false to cancel." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html

Comment: I don't even know how I missed that because I actually read the documentation...  Thanks anyway